# flink - how to use state as cache

Tags: apache-flink

I want to read history from state. if state is null, then read hbase and update the state and using onTimer to set state ttl. The problem is how to batch read hbase, because read single record from hbase is not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to cache/mirror state from an external database in Flink, the most performant approach is to stream the database mutations into Flink -- in other words, turn Flink into a replication endpoint for the database's change data capture (CDC) stream, if the database supports that.

I have no experience with hbase, but https://github.com/mravi/hbase-connect-kafka is an example of something that might work (by putting kafka in-between hbase and flink).

If you would rather query hbase from Flink, and want to avoid making point queries for one user at a time, then you could build something like this:

```
              -> queryManyUsers -> keyBy(uId) -> 
streamToEnrich                                 CoProcessFunction
              -> keyBy(uID) ------------------->
```

Here you would split your stream, sending one copy through something like a window or process function or async i/o to query hbase in batches, and send the results into a CoProcessFunction that holds the cache and does the enrichment.

When records arrive in this CoProcessFunction directly, along the bottom path, if the necessary data is in the cache, then it is used. Otherwise the record is buffered, pending the arrival of data for the cache from the upper path.

Comment: I want to read the record of the same user from hbase only once, so I used keyed state to remember the record i have read. But in this way, I can only read single record from hbase. I want to batch read different users' records from hbase, at the same time I want to use keyed state as catch. Is there a way to solve the problem?

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more explicit about my proposal for solutions where flink is querying hbase.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. There is a point I am not clear. The users needed to query are in the streamToBeEnriched, if I build like this streamToBeEnriched->queryManyUsers->keyBy(userId) , there is no need to use state as cache, and all the records  will get from hbase.

Comment: You could split streamToBeEnriched. Then the operator with the cache would only have to wait for the stream querying hbase if the cache is empty.