# Most efficient way in Flink to perform a sql lookup on a datastream

Tags: sql, apache-flink

Given a datastream from Kafka, is there a built in way, or what is the most efficient way to perform a SQL lookup.

For example, having a stream object connected to a sql table and joining it with the Kafka datastream. Given a sql table that can be updated on an ad hoc basis,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the obvious answer is to use Flink's SQL API, which is [documented here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/).

There's also some [Flink SQL training](https://github.com/ververica/sql-training) that includes a docker-based setup where you can use Flink's SQL client to make interactive SQL queries against a Kafka datastream.

Comment: Looking at your comment and the link to the training, maybe i havent explained correctly the issue, or perhaps i misunderstand the documentation. I have one DataStream reading from kafka, and seperately i have a sql server containing a lookup table. Based on the data being received from Kafka, i want to perform a lookup against the SQL table. 

Is there some option to connect to an external SQL server table via a Stream which detects any changes and join it with the other datastream from Kafka.

Comment: I see. The best approach is to mirror the external database into Flink state by streaming in its CDC stream. Or you can use async i/o to manage querying the DB from Flink. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52042160/2000823 for more.